# How can I find the indices in a numpy array that meet multiple conditions?

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have an array in Python like so:

Example:

```
>>> scores = numpy.asarray([[8,5,6,2], [9,4,1,4], [2,5,3,8]])
>>> scores
array([[8, 5, 6, 2],
   [9, 4, 1, 4],
   [2, 5, 3, 8]])
```

I want to find all `[row, col]` indices in `scores` where the value is:

1) the minimum in its row

2) larger than a threshold

3) at most .8 times the next largest value in the row

I would like to do it as efficiently as possible, preferably without any loops. I've been struggling with this for a while, so any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Aren't goals number 1) and 3) conflicting?

Comment: @JB333 Maybe it's a trick question and the answer is to always return an empty array (without any loops). ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should go something along the lines of

```
In [1]: scores = np.array([[8,5,6,2], [9,4,1,4], [2,5,3,8]]); threshold = 1.1; scores
Out[1]: 
array([[8, 5, 6, 2],
       [9, 4, 1, 4],
       [2, 5, 3, 8]])

In [2]: part = np.partition(scores, 2, axis=1); part
Out[2]: 
array([[2, 5, 6, 8],
       [1, 4, 4, 9],
       [2, 3, 5, 8]])

In [3]: row_mask = (part[:,0] > threshold) & (part[:,0] <= 0.8 * part[:,1]); row_mask
Out[3]: array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [4]: rows = row_mask.nonzero()[0]; rows
Out[4]: array([0, 2])

In [5]: cols = np.argmin(scores[row_mask], axis=1); cols
Out[5]: array([3, 0])
```

At that moment if you're looking for actual coordinate pairs, you can just `zip` them:

```
In [6]: coords = zip(rows, cols); coords
Out[6]: [(0, 3), (2, 0)]
```

Or if you're planning to look those elements up, you can use them as is:

```
In [7]: scores[rows, cols]
Out[7]: array([2, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're going to have a hard time doing this with out any for loops (or at least something that performs such a loop but might be *disguising* it as something else), seeing as how the operation is only dependent on the row and you want to do it for each row. It's not the most efficient (and what is may depend on how frequently conditions 2 and 3 are true) but this will work:

```
import heapq
threshold = 1.5
ratio = .8
scores = numpy.asarray([[8,5,6,2], [9,4,1,4], [2,5,3,8]])

found_points = []
for i,row in enumerate(scores):
    lowest,second_lowest = heapq.nsmallest(2,row)
    if lowest > threshold and lowest <= ratio*second_lowest:
        found_points.append([i,numpy.where(row == lowest)[0][0]])
```

You get (for the example):

```
found_points = [[0, 3], [2, 0]]
```